# How to authenticate a user on Substrate chain in Rust?

Tags: rust, substrate, polkadot

I want to verify whether a potential user is actually a user on a Substrate chain. For this purpose, I am looking for an API that would let me perform this task. While going through the [tutorial](https://substrate.dev/substrate-collectables-workshop/#/1/introduction), I used `ensure_signed` multiple times. So, I am looking for something on those lines.

My intention, as of now, suggestions most welcome, are as follows:

A third-party service (totally different and outside from the substrate chain) doing the following:

1. Digitally signed transaction
2. If 1 succeeds, I will move forward to my other logic and steps else I will stop.

```
func validate_user(user_account_id){
    if is_user(user_account_id){
        if user_authenticate(user_account_id, digital_sign){
            return True
        }
    }
    return False
}
```

I am under the impression that there is only one way of performing authentication and that is digitally signed transaction.

Comment: You want to do this inside of the runtime? `ensure_signed` does not actually do any signature verification, this happens earlier in the transaction queue. If you gave us some pseudo code of what you wanted to do, that would help.

Comment: I want to do this in service outside of the substrate chain - like a third-party service.
Updating pseudocode in a sec.

Thanks for your comment.

Comment: At that point, you need to use the correct cryptographic libraries, like `sr25519`: https://github.com/w3f/schnorrkel

This is also implemented in JS:
https://github.com/polkadot-js/common/tree/master/packages/util-crypto